# django dynamic filtered form

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, menu

I am converting a project from php to Django and have run into the issue of filtered menus. I have a form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    genus = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    #    species
    species = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    #   island group
    island_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Localitymayor.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup').exclude(islandgroup="n/a").order_by('islandgroup'), empty_label=_("Not Specified"))
    #   island name
    island_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Localitymayor.objects.values_list('islandname', flat=True).distinct('islandname').exclude(islandname="n/a").order_by('islandname'), empty_label=_("Not Specified"))
```

my template is along the lines of:

```
<form action="{% url cdrs_search %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

Now I want to filter the output of the `island_name` depending on the selection of `island_group`. In my php project I managed this with an ajax onChange call to another php script. However, I am a little lost how to do this in Django. As this is my first time working with ajax in Django I would appreciate any suggestions as to the best practice way of dealing with this simple but common filtered menu problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would it be any different in Django? You still need an Ajax onChange function calling a server-side view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a modification of code from the ticket form of betspire.com. This code snippet depends on having jQuery loaded.

Here's the javascript you need:

```
    function update_select(select, data) {
        select.find('option').remove();
        select.append($('<option value="">-------</option>'));
        for (var i in data) {
            select.append($('<option value="'+data[i][0]+'">'+data[i][1]+'</option>'));
        }
    }

    $('select[name=island_group]').live('change', function(e) {
        $.get(
            '{% url island_name_choices_for_island_group %}',
            {
                'island_group': $(this).val(),
            },
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });
```

Add to urls:

```
url(
    r'island_name/choices/$',
    'island_name_choices_for_island_group', {
    }, 'island_name_choices_for_island_group',
),
```

Add to views:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

from models import *

def island_name_choices_for_island_group(request, qs=None):
    if qs is None:
        # Change the default QS to your needs
        # (you didn't specify it)
        qs = Island.objects.all()

    if request.GET.get('island_group'):
        # assuming your Island model has an FK named island_group to model IslandGroup
        qs = qs.filter(island_group__pk=request.GET.get('island_group'))

    results = []
    for choice in qs:
        results.append((choice.pk, choice.name))

    return http.HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(results))
```

Please let me know if you run in any troubble.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code with some modifications but I am still unable to get the ajax to update the menu. Specifically I am unsure about my html. Can I possibly send you the code I have for you to take a look?

Comment: First: is there any python error in the ajax view (verify the ajax view by opening the url or use firebug) ? Second: is there any javascript error (use firebug) ? Third: add "console.log" statements or use firebug to debug the javascript and check that expected code is run with expected parameters :)

Comment: Ok - I got it working now. Though I am still unclear about the `qs=None` but. Could you explain why that is necessary?

Comment: Hehehe I am pleased that you ask. Two things: 0) it is a best practice to allow overriding parameters of a view (you could use the same view with another queryset in another url) and 1) keyword argument values are evaluated when the views are imported and thus if you set qs=MyModel.objects.... then it would not be thread safe. It also goes for arguments like extra_context. As you can see in code by guru James Bennett, extra_context kwarg value is None rather than {} for thread safety: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/registration/views.py#cl-16

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a view for your ajax script to hit to ask for a list of names based on a group, e.g.

```
# views.py
def ajax_endpoint(request):
    # leaving error checking to you
    group = request.GET.get('group')
    names_list = avalable_names(group) # some function or db call
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(names_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do this in javascript. You can make a call to a separate view using an ajax request from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The job of this separate view is to handle the server side sorting of your model data (island)name based on the user selected island_group). Then you can use javascript to repopulate your forms using the response from the view. Some good examples on how to do this can be found [in this blog](http://www.nerdydork.com/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django.html) (it is a little dense, but is very useful), [in an article on how to do this with javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml), and [in this tutorial](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/) (highly recommended).

There is also a good SO post that explains why it is necessary to do it this way, it may be a bit pedantic to include but it helped clarify things for me while creating filtered forms. Just look at the  [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419908/getting-selected-value-from-drop-down-box-in-a-html-form-without-submit) for that question.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. I will see if I can make it work for me.